# C# excel interop : How to sort out Top 5 lowest score based on department?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I want to use this data[image] and **sort out Top 5 lowest score based on each department**. Any suggestion on how should i start? should i create array based on department? 
The end result should be like this [image]

Comment: The kind of data is way overdue to be in a Database. If you do that, it is a simple SQL query to group by Department, Sort by Score and discard the bottom 5 - all in one operation. If you got to stay with Excel (wich I can again only advise against): load the whole table into memory. Then use LINQ for equivalent filtering.

Answer (score 1):

```
 new List<Employee> {
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 1, Name = "A", Department = "D1", MonthlyScore = 10  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 2, Name = "B", Department = "D2", MonthlyScore = 40  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 3, Name = "C", Department = "D2", MonthlyScore = 12  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 4, Name = "D", Department = "D3", MonthlyScore = 15  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 5, Name = "E", Department = "D3", MonthlyScore = 17  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 6, Name = "F", Department = "D3", MonthlyScore = 122  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 7, Name = "G", Department = "D4", MonthlyScore = 17 },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 8, Name = "H", Department = "D4", MonthlyScore = 199  },
            new Employee { EmployeeNumber = 9, Name = "I", Department = "D4", MonthlyScore = 100 },
        }
        .GroupBy(x => x.Department)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
            foreach (Employee item in x.OrderBy(y => y.MonthlyScore).Take(2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", item.EmployeeNumber, item.Department, item.MonthlyScore));
            }
        });

/*
Output:
D1
1, D1, 10
D2
3, D2, 12
2, D2, 40
D3
4, D3, 15
5, D3, 17
D4
7, D4, 17
9, D4, 100
*/
```

Comment: But after it select the first 5 it still looping the last name until the last row so i get 800 rows of the last person name

Comment: i get output like this 17035349 | PM | 70
17035366 | M1 |110
17035368 |   SMT BK |150
17125604 | MT | 0
17125641 | M1 | 0
18015697 | SMT BK | 0
18085955 | QA | 0
18106097 | M1 | 350
19026345 | ME |0
19046527 | SMT| 80

Comment: i cant understand that output. separate each line with a :.